# Access settings app views

Tags: android, view, settings

My main goal is to redesign the settings application listview.
I send the user to the "about device" screen by this code:

```
 Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS);
```

and startActivity function.
I need to access the listview in this screen,just to change item color or something like that,is it possible?
I heard CleanMaster application does something familiar.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible?

No. You cannot modify the UI of another application. Moreover, that activity's UI varies by device, and it may not even exist on some devices.

Comment: I assume settings application always show a listview,and it's not my problem if the UI may change.

Comment: @ZachBublil: "I assume settings application always show a listview" -- that is not required, though it is typical. However, the items in the list, and their order, change by Android OS version and device manufacturer. And, as I noted, you cannot modify that UI anyway, as it is in another app. There may be some options here on rooted devices (e.g., something with Xposed).